# DVD drive unable to eject/load and won't recognize/play anything

Tags: 12.04, dvd, eject

I am running 12.04, and my drive is a Plextor PX 880SA.

My DVD player does not work. Today was my first attempt at trying to use it in months, or maybe even longer, so I'm not sure how long it has been inoperative.

I can't even open the drive.  I've tried a number of terminal commands, including:

1. `eject`
2. `sudo eject`
3. `sudo eject /dev/sr0`
4. `file /dev/sr0`
5. `sudo eject -i off`

The error message I keep receiving is:

```
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The light on the drive will light up, but it still won't eject/open. I was able to manually open it by sticking a pin in the hole of the drive, but it is still a "dead" drive. It won't automatically close with a light push, and won't recognize the loaded DVD.

Comment: As you may be aware, this looks like [bug 875543](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/875543). I recommend using the "This bug affects..." link to indicate you are affected (you'll need to have a Launchpad account), and posting any information there that you have and hasn't already been posted there. Generally, work on bugs like this should be done on Launchpad, and tends to be [considered off-topic for Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: To anyone who may find this: `cdrdao unlock /dev/sr0` fixed this for me.